# MongoDb Norm serialization

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, norm

I know this is subjective, but how good is the norm serializer, particularly related to serialization of complex objects that are cyclic. Essentially I have big chunk of deserialized xml message, coming in over the wire, several hundred times a minute, which has some 47 or 57 classes when deserialized. Would Norm be able to handle it, in a normal run of the mill fashion.

Any experiences to share would be welcome. 
  Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoRM is no longer being actively maintained. I used the 10gen C# provider instead and it dealt with very deep cyclic serialization easily. I recommend it.